# How can I connect the H-bridge L9110 with the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio

How can I connect the H-bridge L9110 with the Raspberry Pi model B's 26 pin GPIO header?

Comment: Personally I'd connect it according to the datasheet.  Have you the datasheet for the device  you plan to use?

Comment: i want to do a Wheel chair project for handicapped using a web cam

Comment: The L9110 can only drive small motors (less than an amp).  What are you going to do with the motor?  Have you bought the chip or a motor driver board incorporating the chip?  You need to edit any additional information into your question.

Answer (score 3):

Calm down, there's no need to use exclamation marks and bold fonts.

It's quite simple to connect those on a Pi. For the circuit, this is it:
[image]

**To drive the chip:**

- Simply send a HIGH for clockwise or LOW for counterclockwise  to GPIO23 (Pin 16, brown wire) and then send a PWM signal on GPIO24 (Pin 18, orange wire) to control the speed.

  - For counter-clockwise, set the PWM value to your desired speed. Set the pin to 0 or LOW to stop.
  - If you are going clockwise, your PWM value should be reverse (100 minus speed). Setting the value to 100 or HIGH will stop the motor.

This is if you follow my schematics, but you can use any GPIO pin you want.

Comment: In your attached image, what is term used to denote this white board?

Comment: it's not my Raspberry Pi's model !!!

Comment: @Ahmad All Raspberry Pis have the same GPIO output. The model doesn't matter.

Comment: @GauravDave Breadboard. It's called a breadboard.

Comment: @pandalion98, thanks for you dig.. What does "To another external supply" mean..Is that a external battery supply?

Comment: @user1050619 Yup. Battery or PSU, as long as it can handle your motors.

Comment: Thanks @pandalion98 , I'm using the same motor that's on your circuit diagram that I got part of my raspberry pi kit...How much power does it need(4 AA batteries will be good enough) ? Can't I power it using my pi itself?

Comment: @user1050619 I have no idea about your motor or your requirements. Why not try? Just don't blow up your Pi while you're at it.